# Консольный клиент mysql не позволяет вводить символы кириллицы

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Я установил mysql-server на ubuntu 15.04, но консольный клиент mysql не позволяет вводить символы кириллицы (при нажатии клавиши ничего не происходит, курсор остается на месте). В обычном терминале, если не запускать клиент mysql, русские символы работают. Запрос

```
show variables like 'char%';
```

дает следующий вывод:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Запросы выборки данных, например

```
select * from catalogs;
```

отображают символы кириллицы корректно. Мне необходимо вводить символы кириллицы именно через терминал в клиент mysql в учебных целях. История команд в клиенте работает для запросов, набранных латинницей. Если в запросе были символы кириллицы - они не отображаются, как будто и не вводились. Команда

```
which mysql
```

дает

```
/usr/bin/mysql
```

Для команды

```
dpkg -S $(which mysql)
```

вывод следующий:

```
mysql-client-core-5.6: /usr/bin/mysql
```

К серверу подключаюсь локально (все на одной машине) через графический эмулятор терминала - открываю его нажатием ctrl+alt+T, затем ввожу команду

```
mysql -uroot -p123
```

Comment: 1. история команд в клиенте работает? 2. что выдаёт `which mysql; dpkg -S $(which mysql)`?

Comment: 1. история команд в клиенте работает? 2. каким образом вы подключены к серверу — удалённо или локально? если удалённо — из какой операционной системы и по какому протоколу? если локально — где вызываете программу *mysql*? — в одной из виртуальных консолей или в «графическом» эмуляторе терминала?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему удалением всех пакетов mysql и установкой их из архива, заргуженного с mysql.com.
До этого ставил так:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 Server

В файле конфигурации /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d.mysql.cnf В блоке [mysqld], прописать

```
[mysqld]
...
...
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
...
```

В блоке [client] прописать

```
[client]
...
...
# ЗАКОМЕНТИРОВАТЬ !
#default-character-set = utf8_general_ci
#default-character-set = utf8
...
```